# Python: file oldest date value in a list of objects

Tags: python

While I understand that you can get the oldest date in a list of dates by using `min(list_of_dates)`, say I have have a list of dictionaries which contain arbitrary keys that have date values:

```
[{key1: date1}, {key2: date2}, {key3: date3}]
```

Is there a built-in method to return the dictionary with the oldest date value? Do I need to iterate over the list, and if so what would that look like?

Comment: What output would you expect? Can these dictionaries have any other values in them other than dates? Is there just *one* value per dictionary?

Comment: Only one date per dict in the list?

Comment: Are your objects indeed dictionaries with only one key/value pair?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's just the one key, with the single date value. Your answer is correct; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the minimum `date` value  *per dictionary*:

```
min(list_of_dictionaries, key=lambda d: min(d.values()))
```

This would work with just 1 or with multiple values per dictionary in the list, provided they are all `date` objects.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> import random, string
>>> def random_date(): return date.fromordinal(random.randint(730000, 740000))
... 
>>> def random_key(): return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10)])
... 
>>> list_of_dictionaries = [{random_key(): random_date() for _ in range(random.randint(1, 3))} for _ in range(5)]
>>> list_of_dictionaries
[{'vsiaffoloi': datetime.date(2018, 1, 3)}, {'omvhscpvqg': datetime.date(2020, 10, 7), 'zyvrtvptuw': datetime.date(2001, 7, 25), 'hvcjgsiicz': datetime.date(2019, 11, 30)}, {'eoltbkssmj': datetime.date(2016, 2, 27), 'xqflazzvyv': datetime.date(2024, 9, 1), 'qaszxzxbsg': datetime.date(2014, 11, 26)}, {'noydyjtmjf': datetime.date(2013, 6, 4), 'okieejoiay': datetime.date(2020, 12, 15), 'ddcqoxkpdn': datetime.date(2002, 7, 13)}, {'vbwstackcq': datetime.date(2025, 12, 14)}]
>>> min(list_of_dictionaries, key=lambda d: min(d.values()))
{'omvhscpvqg': datetime.date(2020, 10, 7), 'zyvrtvptuw': datetime.date(2001, 7, 25), 'hvcjgsiicz': datetime.date(2019, 11, 30)}
```

or just one value per dictionary:

```
>>> list_of_dictionaries = [{random_key(): random_date()} for _ in range(5)]
>>> list_of_dictionaries
[{'vmlrfbyybp': datetime.date(2001, 10, 25)}, {'tvenffnapv': datetime.date(2003, 1, 1)}, {'ivypocbyuz': datetime.date(2026, 8, 9)}, {'trywaosiqm': datetime.date(2022, 7, 29)}, {'ndqmejmfqj': datetime.date(2001, 2, 13)}]
>>> min(list_of_dictionaries, key=lambda d: min(d.values()))
{'ndqmejmfqj': datetime.date(2001, 2, 13)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Per the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), `min` supports an arbitrary key function to specify what to compare on. If you require more specific behavior, you may also consider `sorted` instead.